# JSONP not working for cross domain AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I've look at all the cross-domain ajax questions, and still cannot figure out what is wrong with my JSONP request. All I am trying to do is get the contents of an external page, cross domain using JSONP. Unfortunately, firefox still gives this:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://stackoverflow.com/?_=1415036764663. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Code:

```
var url = "http://stackoverflow.com";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    datatype: "jsonp",   //allows cross-domain ajax without cors (GET only)
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    timeout: 15000,

    success: function(html) {
        console.log(html);
    }
});
```

Comment: What URL are you trying to access?  JSONP (or CORS) doesn't just magically let you access arbitrary domains via AJAX.  The sites you are accessing need to *support* these things.  I'm assuming `stackoverflow.com` doesn't support JSONP.  If you want data from StackOverflow, you need to use the API: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Answer (score 1):

You have a small typo there:

```js
…
dataType: "jsonp", // dataType instead of datatype
…
```

JavaScript variables and object properties are case-sensitive.